# Values obtained from a JSON file stay on parsing function and don't get assigned to a global variable

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble passing some values around.

I have this structure, very simple right now since I'm trying to figure out what the problem is.

What I want is to have the JSON data in variables like `examples` and `chapters`. The information from the file loads perfectly, I can see it with `alert` or `console.log`.

```
// global variables
var JSONObject = false;
var chapters = false; // or Array depends on what I'm trying
var examples = false; // or Array depends on what I'm trying
var ajax_request = false;
var url_json = "js/database.json";

// start the process, for now
load_json_data();
console.log( JSONObject ); // outputs false

function load_json_data() {

    // new request
    ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // do the request
    ajax_request.open( "GET", url_json, true );
    ajax_request.send( null );

    // function to parse the JSON data
    ajax_request.onload = parse_json;

    // return value
    return true;
}

function parse_json() {
    if ( ajax_request.readyState === 4 && ajax_request.status === 200 ) {
        // parse the JSON file
        JSONObject = JSON.parse( ajax_request.responseText );

        // do something with the loaded data
        temp();
    }
    return true;
}

function temp() {
    console.log( JSONObject ); // outputs the JSON content if async = true
                               // with async false, it never reaches this function
// here all the information is available and chapters and sections have values
chapters = JSONObject.chapters;
examples = JSONObject.examples;
}
```

The idea is that the `temp` function, which will be called something else, registers values obtained from the JSON file to be used in other functions, like `construct_select()`, which will create a `select` control in the page. It doesn't have to be a separate function; it could be in the same `parse_json()` function, but right now it's in `temp()` because I was trying a few things as neatly as I could.

So I want to execute `load_json`, `parse_json`, and any other function that I need from a central function, but to do that, I need those functions to pass the values to other variables.

Usually, I try to have one function for controlling the flow of the script, making all the decisions, and the rest of the functions just execute what they have to do and return a state (true/false) or a value if needed.

I hope I explained myself properly, but if any more info is required, just let me know.

**Update 1:**
I imagine that the problem is related to the asynchronous process, but shouldn't that have been solved using `onload` before calling the parsing function? Also, if I change the async parameter to false, it doesn't improve.

**Update 2:**
If a function is called/executed by an event listener, `JSONObject` is available to that function. I still don't get how or why, but that helps to what I want to do in the end. It still doesn't allow to have one function controlling the flow and deciding what to execute, but I can try to leave that to events. I'm still trying to figure out if I can pass the value to a global variable usable by functions, not triggered by listeners.

Comment: You declare 'chapters', but don't declare 'sections' at the top. Apart from that it looks moderately plausible. I don't see details on when, where & what data you are looking for and *not* finding.

Comment: Generally, using jQuery & perhaps more parameter-passing & fewer globals might be cleaner. Instead of JSONObject, name it say BookInfo or BookResult -- if that's what it is. I'm not going to say that a global state is wrong, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sections is a typo, should be examples, I'll edit that. jQuery is out of the question, I prefer to leave all the control inside the parsing function that use jQuery.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Does your code not work? Are you trying to design something else?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
isArray(obj){
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'){
    return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
}
function logIt(data){
  var dc = data.chapters, de = data.examples;
  if(isArray(dc)){
    console.log(dc.join());
  }
  else{
    console.log(dc);
  }
  if(isArray(de)){
    console.log(dc.join());
  }
  else{
    console.log(de);
  }
}
function getJSON(url, callback, method, data, async){
  var req, m;
  m = !method ? 'GET' : method.toUppercase();
  if(!data)data = null;
  if(!async)async = true;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    req = new XMLHttpRequest;
  }
  else{
    req = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  req.open(m, url, async);
  req.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
      callback(eval('('+req.responseText+')'));
    }
  }
  req.send(data);
}
getJSON('js/database.json', logIt);
```

Please notice the scroll bar to the right. The thing is that you have to make sure whatever is going to happen after your request happens `onreadystatechange`, therefore if you assign anything to an Object `onreadystatechage` that does not mean that it will be automatically accessible to your other JavaScript. The solution is to have a callback with your code inside it. This callback must have a single argument in this case, which will be passed the evaluated `responseText`, which comes back as a String. To turn this String into JavaScript `.eval()` is used within `getJSON`. You may want to store your information on a `.php` page instead of `.json`. Your PHP might look something like:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['textInput']) && trim($_POST['textInput']) !== ''){
    echo json_encode($_POST);
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer PHPglue, but I fail to see how your syntax is better except for including IE < 7. My function above is simple so I can explain my self better without confusing without extra details. Plus adding options for the async, method and send doesn't seem to add any value right now. The only difference I see, is lack of parenthesis on your XMLHttpRequest. If I'm wrong interpreting your answer, please help me understand it.

Comment: The lack of parentheses is alright, as long as it's a Constructor and there are no arguments. I guess I don't fully understand what you are getting at. Do you need to loop over each value and assign them to a new Object?

Comment: Thanks again for a new option. When I try var obj = load_json_data('js/database.json'); console.log(load_json_data.chapters); I get 'undefined'. I tried, just for kicks, console.log( temp.chapters ) and I got the same result, 'undefined'.

Comment: Should be obj.chapters and the like. You would need a JSON object on your page `js/database.json` that has an object with properties `chapters` and `examples` for this to work.

Comment: ups, yes, sorry again for those typos, I'll edit my comment. About what I want, well, as I said, I want the values obtained in the parsing function available globally, or at least in function not descendent from the parsing one. Can't edit that comment any more, but I used the right syntax.